# Missiles have a strange direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

There is a strange behavior when my spaceship fires off some missiles to destroy an enemy. Under certain circumstances, the missiles "jump" and fly away.

This seems to happen when the nearest enemy is destroyed by one missile and all others have no target any more. Then they "jump" and fly away (off the screen).

I still don't know the cause of this problem.

```
void Start () {
    rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

    nearestEnemy = FindClosestTarget("EnemyShipTag");
}
```

Getting the closest target (enemy)

```
GameObject FindClosestTarget(string _target) {

    enemies = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag(_target);

    closest = null;

    distance = Mathf.Infinity;

    _position = this.transform.position;

    foreach (GameObject enemy in enemies) {

        diff = enemy.transform.position - _position;

        curDistance = diff.sqrMagnitude;

        if (curDistance < distance) {
            closest = enemy;
            distance = curDistance;
        }
    }

return closest;

}
```

Calculate movement to nearest enemy if nearestEnemy is not null

```
void FixedUpdate () {


    if (nearestEnemy != null) {//is enemy available?

        Vector2 enemyTarget = nearestEnemy.transform.position;
        Vector2 direction = (Vector2)enemyTarget - rb.position;

        direction.Normalize ();

        float rotateAmount = Vector3.Cross (direction, transform.up).z;

        rb.angularVelocity = -rotateAmount * rotateSpeed;

        float speed = 6f;

        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, nearestEnemy.transform.position, step);

    } else {
        //rocket shall fly straight ahead if there's no target
        rb.velocity = transform.up * speed;
}
```

These functions are part of the EnemyControl.cs-script

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col) {//this function will trigger when there is a collision of our game objects
    //detect collision of the enemy ship with the player ship, or with a player's bullet
    if ((col.tag == "PlayerShipTag") || (col.tag == "MissileUpgradeTag")) {
    EnemyDestroyed ();
}

void EnemyDestroyed () {

Destroy (gameObject);//Destroy the enemy ship

        dead = true;

        PlayerControl.enemiesDestroyed++;


}
```

[image: missile_direction]

Comment: Maybe stupid question ... what happens, when an enemy gets destroyed? Is it set NULL?

Comment: i agree with @nilsK the enemy destroy and enemy create functions would help. it looks as it is being set to null for 1 tick ( forcing the missiles to fly forward) before changing their direction to something off scren that they are then trying to curve towards

Comment: I'm suspicious of this line ```rb.velocity = transform.up * speed;```  because if another enemy spawns, velocity is not unset.

Comment: So I checked the method with 2 enemies. I shot one enemy down and the other got killed by a missile. No enemies are left any more and the nearestEnemy = NULL (according to the console). Hope this helps...

Comment: Your `FixedUpdate` method uses the variable "speed" in the `else` block, which is created in the scope of your `if` statement. How does your code know what "speed" variable is?